# Считывание значения выбранной ячейки из DataGridView, которая выбрана кликом посредством клика по другому DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

Проблема заключается в том, что необходимо получить значение из выбранной ячейки DataGridView, и эта ячейка должна быть выбрана путем клика по ячейке другого DataGridView1. Свойство `DataGridView.CurrentCell.Value` в моём случае не подошло, так как, насколько я понимаю, ячейка не находится в фокусе. Подскажите, пожалуйста, чем я могу воспользоваться для решения данной проблемы? Скрины предоставил. Видно, что если выбрать вторую строку через клик по правому DataGridView1, то id в текстбоксе не изменится.

[image]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: С правым DGV не понятно. У него всего две строки, причем вторая строка пустая, а первая со значком `+`. И какая логика стоит между выбором строки с `+` и зависимостью с первой строкой из другого DGV с надписью "Ник..." ?

Comment: `DataGridView.SelectedCells[0]`?

Comment: @Bulson, зависимость следующая: при выборе ячейки из правого DGV у ячейки считывается индекс номер ряда и передаётся в левый DGV, после чего ячейка с этим индексом автоматически выделяется. То есть, какой ряд выбран в правом DGV, такой и в левом.

Comment: @aepot, к сожалению мне это не подходит, ибо Ваш код выбирает коллекцию ячеек. Мне же необходимо считать значение **только** с ячейки **левого DGV**, которая выбрана в данный момент. Но ячейка должна быть выбрана посредством клика по правому DGV (зависимость я описал в комментарии выше).

Comment: `сожалению мне это не подходит` вы внимаетельней посмотрите: `SelectedCells[0]` - это одна ячейка, а не коллекция. Или вы не знакомы с индексаторами массивов? Или я туплю и ничего не понимаю?

Comment: @aepot, прошу прощения, кодил не в том событии :) 
Ваш код помог, большое спасибо!